# Are "I tied my shoelace" and "I laced my shoe" different?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

According to my study, it seems "**I laced my shoe**" mean I threaded my shoelace through holes and then tied it up. While "**I tied my shoelace**" mean the lace was already in the holes but had not been tied up and I had to tie it up.

So, "**I laced my shoe**" = I threaded my shoelace through holes + tied it up

"**I tied my shoelace**"= the lace was already in the holes but untied + I tied it up

**Is that correct?**

Comment: Yes, you seem correct.

Comment: Two issues with this question: First, you've said something correct and given no explanation for why you doubt it. Second, you've asked opposite questions in the title and body.

Comment: I would use *I laced the shoe* to mean inserting the laces, but not necessarily tying a knot in them at this stage. Workers in shoe retailers would do this reasonably often.

Comment: I think 'unlaced', used about shoes, can mean either 'without laces', or 'with untied laces'. Maybe if you work in a shoe shop one will dominate. If someone said to me 'That little boy has not laced his shoes' and I could see that the laces were present but merely not tied, I would not say or think anything much about that. Try Googling for pictures of unlaced shoes. _Unlaced in British English ADJECTIVE with the lace or laces untied or loose_ [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/unlaced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lace a shoe = thread the shoelace through the holes.  There are many different patterns that you can use to do this.

Tie the laces = use a bow to tie the laces together, usually after putting the shoe on your foot.

But in practical use, you will see some variation, and in context "unlaced" could mean "untied" or with the shoelace loose.